# How to determine which works by DMsGuild adepts are legal for Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, dnd-adventurers-league, playtesting, dms-guild

I was just wondering if there was a list on the wizards site or something that showed which DMsGuild adepts works are AL legal? Or are they all AL legal? I could only find [this list](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/dms-guild-adept-news?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter), but it's old and small.

Looking at other DMsGuild Adepts works, it doesn't seem they are all AL legal, but maybe I'm wrong?

Is there any more rigourous testing for DSguild Adepts AL-legal works, than non DMGA AL-legal works such as, for example, [The Border Kingdoms](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/244431/The-Border-Kingdoms-A-Forgotten-Realms-Campaign-Supplement?src=hottest_filtered&filters=45470_0_0_0_0_0_0_0) supplement?  ? (I assume all AL-Legal works have some testing right?)

I'm running Tomb of Annihilation, and was thinking of adding some bonus content. I thought that DMsGA works becoming AL legal would mean that they had been playtested, and declared "official", so I could rely on their quality, but maybe not?

I don't know... but a complete list of DMsGuild Adepts works that are AL legal would be great, if WotC has made one, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The most complete and up-to-date official list of AL-legal works is found within the ALCC, or Adventurers League Content Catalogue (available for free as part of the [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack)).

The type of work you are referring to is generally known as Community-Created Content, or CCC. The details of how an adventure or supplement becomes a CCC are detailed on p. 67 of the ALCC:

> The CCC adventure design process is fairly open in that the AL administrators provide review for major plot and thematic elements but only rarely provide full critique of the submission. Some things to keep in mind during your creation process:
>
> - Adventures must be appropriate for all audiences; some parental guidance is okay
> - CCC adventures aren’t eligible for some DM Rewards
> - Adventures must be 2 or 4 hours in duration
> - Adventures must be based in the greater Moonsea area; refer to the image below for a general sense of available places

The adventures currently accepted as CCC are listed thereafter on the CCC Adventure List (currently pp. 68-76 of the ALCC). For example, the Border Kingdoms Region Guide supplement is listed on p. 71, with the code 'CCC-GHC-BORDER'.

In the case of the Guild Adept works, those seem to (thus far) have always been "Hard Cover" works, or DDHC. The ALCC offers a complete listing of these works by Season (see complete document, too many pages to list succinctly). The ALCC offers the following guidance regarding Guild Adepts works on pp. 3, 50:

> Also... Guild Adepts! This program serves to highlight some high-performing content contributors from dmsguild.com. Not every submission into the Guild Adept program are valid for Adventurers League play, but every entry is intended to promote the overall seasonal “feel” and flow for its companion hardcover adventure. Guild Adept contributors are selected by Wizards of the Coast directly.

> **What's a Guild Adept?**
>
> A Guild Adept is a highly proficient content creator that was chosen by Wizards of the Coast to provide supplemental material for the hardcover adventure. This content can take many forms, and while not all of that content will be approved for organized play, it can still be used for great home games and inspiration for your players and you, the Dungeon Master! In most cases, Guild Adept content counts as part of the hardcover.

Since DDHC products are part of Seasonal play (i.e. released alongside it instead of ad hoc like CCC), and are reviewed by WoTC's AL team to determine what parts to include or exclude from organized play, they are certainly more vetted than CCC. Whether the level of vetting and testing approaches, meets, or exceeds normal DDAL levels is not covered by any primary source I've found, although there's an official interview about the program ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISctezVL_AM)) that may have more information.

Comment: Thanks, this works pretty well! However it seems Guild adept content is actually not showing up as CCC like you said, but DDHC. So I'm still curious as to whether Guild adept content gets more rigerous playtest than CCC content or not?

Comment: Ah, you're right! I missed answering that part, my bad. Although I couldn't find a clear 100% answer, I've added as much detail as I can from the sources I have. I don't have time to watch the interview I linked, but it *may* hold more answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, "There is a complete list of AL-legal works within the ALCC" is not an accurate statement. The Content Catalog is not updated often enough for it to be considered complete.

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Would "The most complete list" be better? I'm not aware of a more up-to-date official resource, though I'd be happy to hear of one.